# Can't subclass UNNotificationRequest

Tags: swift, uilocalnotification

I wanted to try and subclass a UNNotificationRequest so I can append some additional data to the request but I keep getting a "must call a designated initializer of superclass". The only init that comes up when I try is :

`super.init(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)`

So if I can't subclass a request, is there any other way to send some custom data that can be extracted from the request in didReceive delegate method for the NotificationCenter?

Comment: The problem is that there is no public initializer exposed for `UNNotificationRequest`, only a convenience initializer.

Comment: Okay, thanks JAL. Guess I'll have to change my approach then if the request can't be subclassed